# didEnterRegion and startRangingForBeacons not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I've been having trouble figuring out why startRangingBeaconsInRegion is never called. I know for certain the startMonitoringForRegion is called, and I tried outputting the mRegionsArray as a string and it worked. But the didEnterRegion is not being called however. And I tried walking around back and forth trying to get a signal from my beacons (ie, entering the region), but no luck. I can't wrap my head around what might be wrong, went through a lot of questions on here and none of them mirrored my issue.

I have a Beacons table view and each cell is supposed to contain information (major, minor) on each beacon. Except, these cells aren't being filled because the ranging is not happening. :( I even tried to change it so it only detects one beacon. I know the problem doesn't lie within the Beacon class I created because the loadTestData() function works...

If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.

BeaconTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface BeaconTableViewController : UITableViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

BeaconTableViewController.m

```
#import "BeaconTableViewController.h"
#import "Beacon.h"
#import "BeaconTableViewCell.h"

@interface BeaconTableViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *beaconsTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *beacons;

@end

@implementation BeaconTableViewController

- (void)loadTestData {
    self.beacons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Beacon *beacon1 = [[Beacon alloc] init];
    beacon1.major = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:21311];
    beacon1.minor = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:21331];
    [self.beacons addObject:beacon1];
    Beacon *beacon2 = [[Beacon alloc] init];
    beacon2.major = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10011];
    beacon2.minor = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:10012];
    [self.beacons addObject:beacon2];
    Beacon *beacon3 = [[Beacon alloc] init];
    beacon3.major = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:65535];
    beacon3.minor = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:30136];
    [self.beacons addObject:beacon3];

    [self.beaconsTableView beginUpdates];
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.beacons.count-1 inSection:0];
    [self.beaconsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.beaconsTableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)initRegion {
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"];
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"AB Region"];

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    UIAlertView *alertMonitoring = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"User Notification"
                                                    message:@"Started monitoring for region."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertMonitoring show];

    NSSet *mRegions = [self.locationManager monitoredRegions];
    NSArray *mRegionsArray = [mRegions allObjects];
    NSString *str = [mRegionsArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];

    UIAlertView *alertRegion = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"User Notification"
                                                    message:str
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertRegion show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {


    UIAlertView *alertRanging = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"User Notification"
                                                    message:@"Started ranging."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertRanging show];

    CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];
    Beacon *beacon;
    beacon.major = foundBeacon.major;
    beacon.minor = foundBeacon.minor;

    UIAlertView *alertBeaconFound = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"User Notification"
                                                    message:[[[@"Major: " stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.major]] stringByAppendingString:@", Minor: "] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.minor]]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertBeaconFound show];
    [self.beacons addObject:beacon];
    [self.beaconsTableView beginUpdates];
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.beacons.count-1 inSection:1];
    [self.beaconsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.beaconsTableView endUpdates];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"User Notification"
                                                    message:@"Did enter region."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
//    [self loadTestData];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self initRegion];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.beacons count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BeaconTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BeaconCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Beacon *beacon = [self.beacons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.beacon = beacon;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under iOS 8, Apple added some new requirements to using the location manager (And iBeacons are a Location Manager function)

You have to add the keys `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and/or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to your info.plist file, and then before trying to start monitoring beacons you have to check the authorization status and if it is kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined, you have to make a new call, either `requestAlwaysAuthorization` or `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`

The code might look something like this:

```
  CLAuthorizationStatus status =[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
  if (status ==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
  {
    NSLog(@"Location manager denied");
  }
  theLocManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  theLocManager.delegate = self;
  if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined
      && [theLocManager respondsToSelector: @selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    [theLocManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

(You have to add the check to make sure the location manage responds to the `requestAlwaysAuthorization` or `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` method, since they are only available in iOS >= 8.)

The thing I don't like about this OS change is that if you don't make the request call, your calls to start monitoring beacons fail silently.

Comment: I absolutely agree that iOS 8's silent failure to detect beacons when developers who forget to put in this code is a real problem.  I wish they had made this cause an exception.

Comment: @davidgyoung, have you filed a bug report? We both should.